# Incorrect integration from article

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, bugs

Recently I came across
[an interesting article by Daniel Lichtblau](https://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/Conferences/5832),
where the integral

```
Integrate[Abs[x - y]^n, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}]
```

> `Piecewise[{2/((1 + n)*(2 + n)),Re[n] > -2 }}, Integrate[ Abs[x - y]^n, {x, 0, 1},  {y, 0, 1}, Assumptions ->  Re[n] <= -2]]`

(The same result is obtained in 12.2 and with `RealAbs` instead of `Abs`.) is presented.

As I understand it, the conditions  `Re[n] > -1` and `Re[n] <= -1` should be
in the above. Here are my arguments. First, the expression `2/((1 + n)*(2 + n))`
is negative for `n < -1, n > -2`, whereas the integrand is positive. Second, if
`n < 0`, then we deal with an improper integral. Let us calculate its half by

```
Integrate[RealAbs[x - y]^(-n), {x, 0, 1}, {y, x + \[Epsilon], 1}, 
Assumptions -> \[Epsilon] > 0 && \[Epsilon] < 1/2]
```

> `ConditionalExpression[((-2 + n)^(-1) + \[Epsilon]^(1 - n))/ (-1 + n), Re[n] < 1]`

```
Limit[%,\[Epsilon]->0,Direction->"FromAbove"]
```

> `ConditionalExpression[(2 - 3*n + n^2)^(-1), Re[n] < 1]`

Is it a bug or am I missing something?

Comment: This must be a bug indeed. The integral does not exist for `R[n]<=-1`. This can be seen by a substitution `y -> x + w` which turns the integral into something like $\int \int w^{n} \, \mathrm{d} w \, \mathrm{d} x$.

Comment: Please report it to Wolfram Support and keep us posted on their answers!

Comment: @MarcoB: "Thank You!
We have received your message and will respond shortly."

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes this must be a bug. Splitting the integral "by hand" gives the correct result:

```
Integrate[Integrate[(x - y)^n, {y, 0, x} ], {x, 0, 1}] +Integrate[Integrate[( y - x)^n, {x, 0, y} ], {y, 0, 1}]    
(*ConditionalExpression[2/(2 + 3 n + n^2), Re[n] > -1]*)
```

**addendum**

Mathematica v12.2  evaluates the integral OP asked for only correct if `GenerateConditions -> True` or `GenerateConditions -> False` is included

```
Integrate[Abs[x - y]^n, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1},GenerateConditions -> True]
```

[image]

Case `GenerateConditions -> Automatic`  gives the wrong result.

Comment: Thank you for the workaround with `GenerateConditions->True`.

Comment: You're welcome !